# Fetch data from database using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database

I want to fetch data from database. But the problem is that i want to fetch particular data, which i don't understand how to do it. I have 3 similar records in database with different id. I want that record one by one when i select option in combo box. My code is given below:

```
<select name="q" onchange="myFuncyion()">
<option value="3*10">3*10</option>
<option value="5*10">3*10</option>
<option value="6*10">3*10</option>
</select>
```

the above options are present in the database with diffrent prices. I want the prices. But the problem is this. The same options are present in database with more than one price with diffrent id. But i want that when i select an option so only one price would fetch from database which is correct or equal to that records's id.

I want to write this type of query in database:

```
select * from tablename where size = "$size" and id = "$id"
```

please help how can i do that using ajax?

Comment: May be that you are very clear but i cant understand actually what is your problem, writing js/jquery function myFuncyion or the ajax script that can fetch data from database or both?

Comment: my problem is that i need two variables post from ajax to action page and put it in the query to fetch data from database.

Comment: Ok. One variable will be the value of dropdown(select) and what will be the other value?

Comment: the other value is the id from the help of id it will fetch the correct record because the same options are present in database more than one with diffrent id.

Comment: but i can't understand how can i pass the id using ajax ??

Comment: i have updated my answer. You can check that.

Answer (score 1):

Give id to the selectbox.
    `<select id = "searchBox" name = "whateveryouhavespecified"...>`

```
function myFuncyion(){
    //condition will have the value of your selectbox
    var condition;
    condition = $("#searchBox").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'path to action page',
        data: { action:'getlinks', topic_id: condition},
        success: function(data) {
                //code of what after ajax is done.
        }
    });
}
```

This is an example. Set the variables you want in place where i have set my variables. This way the value of selectbox can be transfered to action page using ajax.

PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='getlinks' && isset($_POST['topic_id']) && $_POST['topic_id']!=''){
    $query = "select * from tablename where fieldname1 = value1 and fieldname2 = value2;"
}
```

Kindly note that i have not mentioned any filteration process here but it is strongly recommended to `filter the values before passing it to query`. I have mentioned what you have asked for only and not entire standard process.